# We have a 2 dropdown list having same value on selection of multiple value of first dropdown second dropdown value is auto selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, bootstrap-4

We have a 2 dropdown list having same value on selection of multiple value of first dropdown second dropdown value is auto selected which have same value as first dropdown

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: 2 dropdown list having same value <select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select><select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

Comment: when select multiple value from 1st drop down second dropdown value is auto selected same as first one how can do this using javascript and jquery

Answer (score 0):

Add `change` event listener to first dropdown and change the value of second dropdown with the selected value of first dropdown.

```js
// javascript
const selectEles = document.querySelectorAll('select');

selectEles[0].addEventListener('change', function() {
    selectEles[1].value = this.value;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select> 
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option> 
    <option value="saab">Saab</option> 
    <option value="opel">Opel</option> 
    <option value="audi">Audi</option> 
</select>
<select> 
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option> 
    <option value="saab">Saab</option> 
    <option value="opel">Opel</option> 
    <option value="audi">Audi</option> 
</select>
```

------ jQuery -------

```js
const selectEles = $('select');
$(selectEles[0]).on('change', function() {
    selectEles[1].value = $(this).val();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select> 
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option> 
    <option value="saab">Saab</option> 
    <option value="opel">Opel</option> 
    <option value="audi">Audi</option> 
</select>
<select> 
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option> 
    <option value="saab">Saab</option> 
    <option value="opel">Opel</option> 
    <option value="audi">Audi</option> 
</select>
```

For multiple values. In order to select multiple values in `dropdown` add `multiple` attribute to `select`. When you set multiple on dropdown, it will return an array of selected options. Check if second dropdown value is present within the selected values, if `yes` set `option` selected property to `true`.

```js
const selectEle = document.querySelector('select#first');
const secondSelectOptions = document.querySelectorAll('select#second>option')

selectEle.addEventListener('change', function() {
    const selectedOptionVals = [...this.selectedOptions].map(option => option.value);
    secondSelectOptions.forEach(option => {
        if(selectedOptionVals.includes(option.value)) {
            console.log('Entering if');
            option.selected = true;
        } else {
            option.selected = false;
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<select id="first" multiple> 
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option> 
    <option value="saab">Saab</option> 
    <option value="opel">Opel</option> 
    <option value="audi">Audi</option> 
</select>
<select id="second" multiple> 
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option> 
    <option value="saab">Saab</option> 
    <option value="opel">Opel</option> 
    <option value="audi">Audi</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: its not allowed to select multiple value If select multiple values from first dropdown the second drop down multiple values are auto selected

Comment: its work for single value but not when select multiple value for the first drop down using attribute multiple="true"

Comment: @AnshJain - See Edit.

Comment: @AnshJain - Where? It is working properly in the above `code snippet`. Use `ctrl` key to select `multiple` values.

Comment: it was select multiple value in first dropdown but after selected multiple values in first drop down it will not auto select the second drop down value it went else {
            option.selected = false;
        } condition

Comment: How come? It is working properly in the snippet, Where is it not working?

Comment: it was not enter in the if condition thats the reason its not auto select the second drop down value

Comment: It is entering in the `if` block, see I have added `console` in it. Please clarify where are you testing.

Comment: I am tested through developer tool

Comment: it will reach till this statement if(selectedOptionVals.includes(option.value)) when the statement is not getting correct  it will enter the else condition and execute it

Comment: @AnshJain - You need to reproduce the issue. I can't see your `code` nor `developer tool`. You can create new thread or provide the working fiddle as well with the input and expected `output` . Welcome to `stackoverflow` and have look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.